# linux bash unexpected output of echo

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file test.xml with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <date>20170809</date>
  <settlement_date>20170810</settlement_date>
</root>
```

I ran linux commands:

```
settle_date=""$(cat test.xml | grep settlement_date | sed -e 's/settlement_date//g' -e 's/[<>\/ \t\n]//g')""
echo $settle_date
echo $settle_date"LL"
echo ${settle_date}"LL"
echo "${settle_date}LL"
```

The first **echo** returns ***20170810*** (expected), while the last three **echo**'s returns ***LL170810***, unexpected, I do not know why.

Could anyone explain?

My bash version is 4.3.11(1)-release
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use `${settle_date}` instead `$settle_date`?

Comment: Cannot replicate, but the double quotes where you assign to `settle_date` are not necessary, and you should use `echo "${settle_date}LL"`

Comment: I can't reproduce on 4.2.46(1)-release. Which version are you using ?

Comment: @archos If I use ${settle_date}, the result is the same.

Comment: @arco444 I also tried  echo "${settle_date}LL", the result is still the unexpected one.

Comment: @Setop Linux dlserv115 3.13.0-112-generic #159-Ubuntu SMP  x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: If I directly set settle_date="20170810", then all outputs of echo are those expected.

Comment: @AiminHuang, I mean bash version, not linux version. Use echo $BASH_VERSION to get it.

Comment: @Setop My bash version is 4.3.11(1)-release.

Comment: You have DOS/Windows line endings in the XML file, and you are not stripping the `\r` that causes a carriage return before printing `LL`, which then overwrites the `20`...

Comment: @twalberg Yes, finally got the correct output. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all possible ways with `echo` , but didn't work. So, I can suggest to go for `printf`.

```
printf '%s\t' "$settle_date" 'LL'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you gave down vote even if its useful. Have you tried?